# Comparing user input to a predefined array of characters in C programming language

Tags: c, strcmp

I have the following code which is supposed to get user input as commands then check whether the command is predefined. However, for any command entered the output is "**You asked for help**".
I figured that the problem might be related to the way I'm comparing the user input string with the set string(s) but I still need help solving the problem.

```
char command[10];
char set[10];
char set1[10];
strcpy(set, "help");
strcpy(set1, "thanks");

int a = 0;
while (a != 1)//the program should not terminate.
{
   printf("Type command: ")
   scanf("%s", command);
   if (strcmp(set, command))
   {
       printf("You asked for help");
   }
    else if (strcmp(set1, command))
   {
       printf("You said thanks!");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("use either help or thanks command");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (strcmp(set, command))
```

should be

```
if (strcmp(set, command) == 0)
```

The reason is that `strcmp` returns a nonzero value if the LHS or RHS is larger, and zero if they are equal. Since zero evaluates to "false" in a conditional, you'll have to explicitly add the `== 0` test to make it true in the sense that you're expecting, which is equality.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, always length-bound your input while using `scanf()`, like

```
 scanf("%9s", command);
```

for a 10-element `char` array, to avoid buffer overflow by overly-long inputs.

That said, the `if...else` block logic works in below way:

```
if (expression is true) {         // produce a non-zero value, truthy 
   execute the if block
   }
else {                             // expression is falsy
   execute the else block
   }
```

In your case, the controlling expression is `strcmp(set, command)`.

Now, point to note, in case of a **match**, `strcmp()` returns a `0`, in case of **mismatch**, it returns a non-zero value.

Thus,

- If your input **matches** the expected pre-selected string, you'll get a `0` - which will be evaluated as *falsy* and against your expectation, it'll go to the `else` part.
- If your input **does not match** the expected pre-selected string, you'll get a non-zero value which will be evaluated as truthy and once again, the `if` block will be executed erroneously.

So, in your case, you need to change the condition to negate the return value, like

```
   if (!strcmp(set, command))
   {
       printf("You asked for help");
   }
    else if (!strcmp(set1, command))
   {
       printf("You said thanks!");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("use either help or thanks command");
   }
```